# group by aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to perform a GROUP BY 'TeamID' but I get the following error after I insert the GROUP BY clause:

**Column 'po.PlayerWeighting' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.**

Where exactly should I put the GROUP BY clause for it to work where it will group all team weightings to TeamID?

```
SELECT DISTINCT TeamID,
    CASE WHEN TeamID = 0 THEN 0 
    ELSE SUM(po.playerWeighting) OVER(PARTITION BY po.TeamID)
    END TeamWeight,
    ABS(CHECKSUM(NewID())) % 10 + 1 AS Form
    FROM(
        SELECT pl.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pl.TeamID, pl.Position ORDER BY NEWID()) AS Rnk
        FROM(
            SELECT DISTINCT p.PlayerID, p.Position, p.PlayerWeighting, p.FirstName, p.Surname, t.TeamID, t.TeamAbbreviation, f.WeekNumber
            FROM dbo.Fixture f
            INNER JOIN dbo.League l ON f.LeagueID = l.LeagueID
            INNER JOIN dbo.Team t ON l.LeagueID = t.LeagueID
            INNER JOIN dbo.Player p ON t.TeamID = p.TeamID
            WHERE f.WeekNumber = 1) 
            pl) po 
    WHERE (po.Position = 'GK' and po.rnk = 1) OR 
          (po.Position = 'DF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
          (po.Position = 'MF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
          (po.Position = 'FW' and po.rnk <= 2)
          GROUP BY TeamID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for `DISTINCT` after `GROUP BY`,  `SUM() OVER()` is unnecessary since there is already `GROUP BY TeamID`

```
SELECT TeamID,
    CASE WHEN TeamID = 0 THEN 0 
    ELSE SUM(po.playerWeighting)
    END TeamWeight,
    ABS(CHECKSUM(NewID())) % 10 + 1 AS Form
    FROM
    ((...) po
    ) t
WHERE ...
GROUP BY TeamID
```